# How to let member function and top-level function share one class name in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I defined a interface `Key` and its top-level function in `Key.kt` file:

```
interface Key {
    //codes...
}

fun keyOf(vararg content: Any?): Key {
    //codes...
}
```

So, in kotlin, I can write:

```
val key = keyOf(...)
```

But in java, it is:

```
Key key = KeyKt.keyOf(...)
```

A little ugly... so I add the jvm class name setting in `Key.kt`:

```
@file:JvmName("Keys")
@file:JvmMultifileClass
```

Now it becomes:

```
Key key = Keys.keyOf(...)
```

Well, still redundant, so I rename `keyOf` function for java:

```
@JvmName("of")
```

Now it seems brief:

```
Key key = Keys.of(...)
```

But, actually, my favorite is

```
Key key = Key.of(...)
```

Is it possible without companion object?

Comment: Why _not_ use a companion object?  That's the usual way.

Comment: @gidds because IDEA cannot auto import companion function as top-level function, it should be imported manually

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
interface Key {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JvmName("of")
        fun keyOf(vararg content: Any?): Key {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// Kotlin
import Key.keyOf
keyOf(...)
```

```java
// Java
Key.of(...)
```

If you *really `keyOf()` to be a top-level function in Kotlin, you can define functions for Kotlin-only and Java-only use separately.

```kotlin
interface Key {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Deprecated("not for Kotlin", level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN) // not visible to Kotlin sources
        fun of(vararg content: Any?): Key {
            ...
        }
    }
}

@JvmSynthetic // not visible to Java sources
fun keyOf(vararg content: Any?): Key {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Deprecated("not for Kotlin", level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN) will hide both in kotlin and java (at kotlin1.4)

Comment: @FredSuvn Whoops, forgot that `HIDDEN` also sets `ACC_SYNTHETIC` in bytecode. Try `DeprecationLevel.ERROR`.